# brew install mopidy will not install Mopidy

Tags: homebrew, mpd

I followed the instructions [from Mopidy's website](https://docs.mopidy.com/en/latest/installation/osx/) step-by-step including `brew install python`. After running `brew install mopidy` and the apprent successful installation and build of mopidy, it seems to not actually be installed.

This is the result of `brew info mopidy`:

```
me ~:$ brew info mopidy
mopidy/mopidy/mopidy: stable 2.0.1, HEAD
Extensible music server written in Python
http://www.mopidy.com/
Not installed
From: https://github.com/mopidy/homebrew-mopidy/blob/master/mopidy.rb
==> Dependencies
Required: gst-plugins-base --with-libogg --with-libvorbis --with-theora ✔, gst-plugins-good --with-flac --with-jpeg --with-libshout --with-libsoup --with-speex --with-taglib ✘, gst-plugins-bad --with-faad2 --with-libmms --with-opus ✔, gst-plugins-ugly --with-flac --with-lame --with-libmms --with-libvorbis --with-mad --with-libshout --with-theora --with-two-lame ✔, gst-python ✔, mopidy/mopidy/python-pykka ✔, mopidy/mopidy/python-tornado ✔, mopidy/mopidy/python-requests ✔
==> Requirements
Required: python ✔
==> Caveats
To have launchd start mopidy/mopidy/mopidy now and restart at login:
  brew services start mopidy/mopidy/mopidy
Or, if you don't want/need a background service you can just run:
  mopidy
```

If I run `mopidy`:

`-bash: mopidy: command not found`

Comment: Does `brew doctor` tell you to fix anything?

Comment: Yes,

`Warning: Unbrewed header files were found in /usr/local/include.
If you didn't put them there on purpose they could cause problems when
building Homebrew formulae, and may need to be deleted.`



Followed by a list of many files in the directory: `/usr/local/include/node/`

Comment: Following this guide to uninstall Node.js http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11177954/how-do-i-completely-uninstall-node-js-and-reinstall-from-beginning-mac-os-x uninstall appears to be successful

Comment: Despite successful uninstall of Node and `brew doctor` saying `Your system is ready to brew.` The mopidy issue remains the same.